# Why does HasMoreResults return true when Count returns 0?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB v 1.5.2 (not ready to upgrade quite yet).

`IDocumentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync().Count == 0`, but `IDocumentQuery.HasMoreResults == true`.  This is causing an (for lack of a better word) infinite loop, which blew out my RSUs.  I'm doing an "SELECT TOP 1..." SQL query.

Comment: You are hitting a bug. Can you please contact us at askcosmosdb @ microsoft.com.

Comment: That's what I figured, as this only recently became an issue.  I contacted support via Twitter, and then they told me to post here.  You want me to now send an email to the above address (making 3 different methods of communications of the same thing)?  I can do it, but I just want to make sure that's the intent here.

Comment: @user2654850 Mention the complete query which you are trying to execute